# How to resolve checkmarx issue of process control type?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, checkmarx

I am working on a VC++ MFC project. Now it uses checkmarx scan. It shows a process control issue in report like below.

> Method delayHook at line 134 of Host Tools/ICC/_DEV/ICC.CPlusPlus/globalProcess.cpp loads a library whose name or location is influenced by input from the client in the "Test.dll" element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly validated, in delayHook at line 134 of Host Tools/ICC/_DEV/ICC.CPlusPlus/globalProcess.cpp. Executing commands or loading libraries from an untrusted source or in an untrusted environment can cause an application to execute malicious commands.

This is the code causing the issue.

```
    FARPROC hMod = (FARPROC)LoadLibrary ("Test.dll");
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this checkmarx item? Since I am new to VC++, I didn't understood it correctly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular static code analyzers, but I assume that it's complaining about your use of relative path. By doing so, an attacker could start your application and set the current working directory to a directory that has a malicious *Test.dll* version. By doing this, they have injected their code into your process. To prevent this attack vector, always pass a fully qualified pathname to `LoadLibrary` (and while you're at it, replace the call into the ANSI version, `LoadLibraryA`, with a call into the Unicode version, `LoadLibraryW`).

Comment: Also, LoadLibrary() returns `HMODULE`, not `FARPROC`

Comment: @IInspectable is correct. The secure way of writing your code is by using absolute paths. I've checked the Checkmarx query for the Process Control vulnerability and it does search for absolute paths